# How to use a Func or Action in a loop instead of local variables?

Tags: c#, func

I'm refactoring some old code and I have the following loop:

```
while (true)
{
    if (stopLoop.IsStopRequested || ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (worker.IsPaused)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(delay);
        continue;
    }

    if (wait)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(delay);
        wait= false;
        continue;
    }

    //much more code here...
}
```

I would like to combine the `isPaused` and `wait` into one block and was thinking of using a `Func`.

Would this make sense in this particular case? How would such a `Func` loop like?

Comment: I don't see any sense to make this code more difficult. Since it's already as simple as it can be. You can't move continue and break to Func (correct me if I'm wrong). So, there is only one line of code (Thread.Sleep) is the same for these if clauses.

Comment: learn a little about the "ManualResetEvent"

Comment: a `Func` is a function, you mean combine them into a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you replace it with one `if`-condition?

```
if (wait || worker.IsPaused)
{
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
    wait = false;
    continue;
}
```

If `wait` is `true` you always set it to `false`. If it's `false` you will set it to `false` again.